# Vector3 Lerp Rotation

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, rotation, z-axis

I want to make a Vector3 rotation in Unity 3D. However, the rotation axes do not make a correct rotation. This is because, I rotate two axes at the same time x and y. I have to separate two rotations. What can I do? Thank you for helping me.

`Vector3 start = new Vector3(0,0,0)`
`Vector3 target = new Vector3(0,0,0)`
`transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(start,target,time)`

Comment: Please post the relevent snippet of your code and what you have already tried.

Comment: Vector3 start = new Vector3(0,0,0); Vector3 target = new Vector3(x,y,z); transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(start,target,time);

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Vector3 rotation through Vector3.Lerp is prone to gimbal lock problems which is what you might be experiencing.

Best way to lerp through rotation is to use the `transform.Rotate();` function.

Alternatively you could use a `Quaternion.Lerp();` and create the start and end Quaternions using `Quaternion.Euler();`. This will yield you the most reliable results since `Quaterion` rotation is more complex than `Vector3` and cancels out any problems you would have in `Vector3` rotations.

Edit: Please remember to post entire snippets of your code. Lerp stands for Linear Interpolation and it requires a t that goes from 0 to 1 where 0 is the starting point and 1 is the end point. Many people use this function wrong and come up with problem. Since i cant see your code however i assumed you did this correctly, but i don't know unless i'd see the actual code :)